# AWS Cloudwatch Guardduty link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In AWS, I am trying to detect Critical alerts in Guardduty and configure cloudwatch which will trigger mails when there is a critical alert in guardduty. 
I found a link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/guardduty_findings_cloudwatch.html  which uses Lambda to create fuctions which will do that but I was looking for more simpler ways without AWS lamda.

Is there is a way to directly configure a cloudwatch alarm which will keep an eye on Guardduty and can use SNS notifications to send mails to desired team.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the CloudWatch event as described in the link you posted. I get alerts via SNS. No Lambda required (although you COULD trigger a Lambda function instead of SNS if you wanted).

Comment: but the link does not provide how to set up SNS for Guardduty. Also I needed notifications for critical alerts on guardduty.  I have setup the event on clouwatch but failing to configure SNS on critical alerts using SNS.

Comment: Okay I got it. I was able to configure SNS for a Guard duty event.
However, I am trying to find out how to get notifications for critical alerts in guardduty. Any inputs from your side on this?